# One tag to fit them all (for model fitting questions)

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

There's a significant part of Stack Overflow looking for solutions for [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) problems (not to be confused with regression testing). However, it seems that some users aren't aware of, or simply don't care about, all the statistical nomenclature that would we ideal for the the question tags (e.g. [regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regression), [linear-regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-regression), [least-squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/least-squares), etc.), and are simply looking for ways to make a function "fit" some data. So that leads to tags like [curve-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curve-fitting), [data-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-fitting), [model-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-fitting), and [function-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-fitting), totalling at ~1.5k total questions, comparable to the question counts for the tags above.

Can we squash the latter four together under [curve-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curve-fitting)?